# how it's answer is 36?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

```
main()
{
   int a=5;
   a= a++ + ++a + ++a + a++ + a++;
   printf("%d",a);
}
```

Comment: This is clearly a troll question.

Comment: Didn't this one last come up within the last 48 hours?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902638/post-and-pre-increment-in-c

Comment: @Johannes it is a valid question though.

Comment: I ran this code in c# (.net framework 4) and the answer was 37 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not defined.

You can find the Committee Draft from May 6, 2005 of the C-standard [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) (pdf)

See section `6.5 Expressions`:

> 2    Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.

and the example:

> 71)    This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
>
> i = ++i + 1;
>
> a[i++] = i;

Comment: Robert, I think it is up to the compiler to decide which operator takes precedence in that case (I think I read somewhere that the spec doesn't say).

Comment: Thanks, I deleted my edit because precedence came into my mind...

Comment: @Robert: Because that is how C is defined (by its standard): the outcome of an expression which modifies the same thing multiple times is undefined. In practice anyone implementation tends to be consistent, but strictly speaking you cannot rely on even that.

Comment: both Dev-cpp and gcc turn up the same answer.

Comment: whereas the modified code like: printf("%d",a++ + ++a + ++a + a++ + a++); printf("\n%d",a); prints the answer as 33 and value of a as 10. a=10 is justifiable, what about 33 as answer!!

Comment: @prathamesh: It doesn't matter. It is not defined in the C-language. gcc allows you to look at the assembler that is produced with the `-S` flag. You can then see how gcc interprets it and why you get the output `36`. But it is still not defined and you still shouldn't use it.

Comment: so how's the operator precedence in C??

Comment: @prathamesh 2nd comment: Everything is justifiable. If it is `10`, `33`, `36`, `1000` or `123456`

Comment: @Lucas it means it's irregular in nature.
isn't there any way to look at it, so as to come up with some conclusive statements?

Comment: @prathamesh: I added the relevant part of the standard to my answer. You will also find everything about precedence of operators in that section. As to why, you get the result: You will have to look a the assembler as I stated earlier. Although I think it would be of little value, since you cannot rely on this compiler behavior in any way.

Comment: thank you @Lucas....i got some more insight.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually *undefined*.

Answer (score -1):

Answer in *undefined* because you've got some situations in which the parser doesn't know how to parse the code..

is `a+++b`: `a + ++b` or `a++ + b`?

Think the fact that usually white space is just ignored when lexing the source code. It may depends upon implementation of the compiler (and some other languages with same `++` operators may choose to give priority to one instead of another) but in general this is not safe.

For example in Java your code line gives 37 as the answer, because it chooses to bind `++` operators in a specific way according to precedence, but it's just a choice..

Comment: Not true. It's well defined where these tokens start and where they end. In `a+++b` this is `a++ + b` (maximal munch principle).

Comment: Oh got it, the undefinition given by the same variable modified multiple times. I thought that my point should be considered too by the way, since it's true :)

Comment: Yeah, it's well defined in an specific implementation but it may change, we spoke about it in a different question.. let me look for it

Comment: whereas the modified code like:
printf("%d",a++  +  ++a + ++a + a++ + a++);
printf("\n%d",a);

prints the answer as 33 and value of a as 10.
a=10 is justifiable, what about 33 as answer!!

Comment: Because you are not assigning to the variable you are incrementing but just prints out the whole sum.